# Check empty fields on php

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I got some insert action with my db and wanted to check on php with foreach loop.I don't understand what is wrong in code because there is no successfull or fail result return.Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$PlaceName = $_POST['placeName'];
$PlaceAddress = $_POST['addressArea'];
$PlacePhone = $_POST['placePhone'];
$PlaceWebsite = $_POST['placeWebsite'];
$OOnWeekday = $_POST['openweekDay'];
$OOnWeekEnd = $_POST['openweekEnd'];
$COnWeekday = $_POST['closeweekDay'];
$COnWeekEnd = $_POST['closeweekEnd'];
$Lati = $_POST['latitude'];
$Longi = $_POST['longitude'];
$btnAddPlace = $_POST['addPlacebut'];


$dbQueryI = $nesnePDO->prepare("INSERT INTO Places
                       (Place_Name,Place_Address,Place_Phone,Place_Web,
                        OOnWeek_Day,OOnWeek_End,COnWeek_Day,COnWeek_End,
                        Lati_P,Longi_P) 
                VALUES (:P_N,:P_A,:P_P,:P_W,
                        :OOWD_P,:OOWE_P,:COWD_P,:COWE_P,
                        :L_P,:L2_P)");


$dbQueryI->bindParam(":P_N",$PlaceName);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":P_A",$PlaceAddress);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":P_P",$PlacePhone);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":P_W",$PlaceWebsite);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":OOWD_P",$OOnWeekday);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":OOWE_P",$OOnWeekEnd);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":COWD_P",$COnWeekday);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":COWE_P",$COnWeekEnd);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":L_P",$Lati);
$dbQueryI->bindParam(":L2_P",$Longi);


$Fields = array($PlaceName,$PlaceAddress,$PlacePhone,$PlaceWebsite,
                $OOnWeekday,$OOnWeekEnd,$COnWeekday,$COnWeekEnd,
                $Lati,$Longi);
$Errors = false;
foreach ($Fields as $fieldname ) 
{
    if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) 
    {
        $response['Errors'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "Some fields are empty so fill them..";
        die(json_encode($response));
        $Errors = true; //Yup there are errors
    }

}

if(!$Errors)
{
        $dbQueryI->execute();
        $response['Errors'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = "That's it..";
        header('Refresh: 3; url=addplaces.php');
        die(json_encode($response));

}
?>
```

Sorry I didn't explain the problem clearly because I was afk.I posted from mobile.
The problem is just want to control the fields whether empty or not.I have a form for the users and want to collect them some info.This is not the entire code but these are the inputs that I'm gonna check.I have no result about any record that add.I tried some different ways but they're not work well.Even some records entirely empty inserted.Just wanted to check that all fields fill and then insert.

Comment: Where are `$PlaceName, $PlaceAddress, ...` and so on defined? Also what are the values of these variables ?

Comment: Don't you want to check if they are empty before you bind them ... ?

Comment: Have you defined $PlaceName,$PlaceAddress,$PlacePhone,$PlaceWebsite,$OOnWeekday,$OOnWeekEnd,$COnWeekday,$COnWeekEnd,$Lati,$Longi variables anywhere?

Comment: They're in a html form. @Rizier123 They take values from user but it's not the case i asked.

Comment: I don't see what your goal is with this code..

Comment: Try changing `die()` to `echo` even if its not the problem `die` is bad practice. Then maybe you will execute the `$Errors = true;` after the `die` and also the rest of the code that `die` will cause the be ignored

Comment: I thought so but i changed nothing happened.

Comment: Your naming  of items between input and the database is interesting - alternate approach? [check-empty-fields-on-php](http://pastebin.com/3k70v5sL). Would a 'validation library' make life easier: [Complex rules made simple](https://github.com/Respect/Validation). All untested!

Comment: I actually got nothing about using libraries.And you're right,it's kinda complex thing that I wrote.for now I just like that way do the things manually.maybe someday I change my mind and learn how to impement them.thank you by the way for advice.I'm gonna check it out

Comment: why question still on hold? I think I explained the question well(a little bit later,sorry about that again) and we solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname]))
```

I think it will always be true, because `$fieldname` is already set to the *value* of the post parameter, not the name of the parameter. You may not be seeing the error message because of `json_encode()` being inside `die()`.

If you want to check that any of these have not been given, you can move this part of the code to the top of the script instead, but it needs some changes.

```
$Fields = array('placeName', 'addressArea', 'placePhone', 'placeWebsite',
                'openweekDay', 'openweekEnd', 'closeweekDay', 'closeweekEnd', 
                'latitude','longitude');
// Use the names as strings here

$Errors = false;
foreach ($Fields as $fieldname ) 
{
    // You can just use empty() here, because it already includes checking isset()
    if(empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
        $response['Errors'] = 0; // Not sure why errors = 0 here
        $response['message'] = "Some fields are empty so fill them..";
        $response = json_encode($response); // Separate json_encode from die
        die($response);

        // This will never execute because the script has already died
        $Errors = true; //Yup there are errors
    }

}
```

Then you will not need to worry about checking `$Errors` afterward, because if there were errors, the script would have already died.

Comment: It defined false default.So it must be true sometime for query works.I don't fully understand your discussable advice but it's kinda logical to me.All I wanna to do is check the fields is empty or not then insert :)) I'm on mobile now so cannot trying right now.I'll check it out when I available.

Comment: Yes it works fine for me!Thank you,this is solved.Final thing is just a curious.What is the difference between the code above or below on php?And sorry for the late response I got couple of meeting.

Comment: @14kubat When you ask "what is the difference between the code above or below", are you referring to why I suggested to move that part of the code to the top of the script?

Comment: Yes,I mean why the code works on the top or why not working correctly below some html stuff or something similar?

Comment: @14kubat In general, I think it makes more sense to put this kind of thing at the beginning because it checks to make sure you have everything you need to do the work. If you don't have what you need, there's no need to try to do any of it. The way you have your code in the question, you are using the POST parameters in your query before you verify that they have been set.